# Python If Else Segmentation 'Invalid Type Comparison' Error in Dataframe

Tags: if-statement, dataframe, comparison, segment

I have a sample dataframe (df_merged_1) shown below:

[image]

The Revenue column is a float64 dtype.  I want to create a new column called 'Revenue_Segment'.  This is what I want the end result to look like:

[image]

Below is the code I used to segment:

```
if df_merged_1['Revenue'] >= 0 and df_merged_1['Revenue'] <= 2200:
    df_merged_1['AUM_Segment'] == 'test1'
else:
    df_merged_1['AUM_Segment'] == 'test0'
```

But the code is not working ... I get the following error:

```
TypeError: invalid type comparison
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not elegant, but this is the only solution I can think of now:

```
# Make a new list to add it later to your df
rev_segment = []

# Loop through the Revenue column
for revenue in df_merged_1['Revenue']:
    if revenue >= 0 and revenue <= 2200:
        rev_segment.append('test1')
    else:
        rev_segment.append('test0')

# Now append the list to a new column
df_merged_1['Revenue_Segment'] = rev_segment
```

Comment: Brilliant!  This worked perfectly ...thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df_merged_1['AUM_Segment'] =  \
    np.where((df_merged_1['Revenue']>=0) & (df_merged_1['Revenue']<=2200), 'test1', 'test2')
```